# Providing help for a modal dialog in Qt

Tags: qt, dialog, modal-dialog, modality

I am working on a Qt application and developing a context sensitive help solution. When a Modal Dialog is active and F1 is pressed, I would desire to be able to interact with the Modal Dialog and help at the same time until the help solution is no longer needed. If I make the Modal Dialog Non-Modal with the F1 event, this allows the parent window to be manipulated which defeats the purpose of making it Modal to begin with.

Does someone have a good solution that allows a user to interact with Help and a Modal Dialog that is better than simply swapping Modality between the Modal Dialog and the Help Dialog? (This is done by setting the Help Dialog property to Qt::ApplicationModal, then when Help Dialog is closed, the Modal behavior returns to the previous Modal Dialog)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the only problem is that user can manipulate the parent window, just call its `setEnabled(false)` to prevent this.

Comment: You could just use an external help viewer which runs as a different process.

Comment: Good idea, but the issue with this solution is that it creates a dependeny and coupling issue. For example, if the number of parent dialogs change or the relationship, the developer needs to go back and fix all the windows intended to be non-active.

Answer (score 0):

> You could just use an external help viewer which runs as a different process. If the number of parent dialogs change or the relationship, the developer needs to go back and fix all the windows intended to be non-active.